# Cannot import JABX XmlPath class

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, unmarshalling, moxy

i'm working on application requiring unmarshalling action.

here's my input file structure :

```
<root>
      <sender>senderCode</sender>
      <receiver>receiverCode</receiver>
      <document-type code="05"/>
      <date>recDate</date>
<root>
```

and to unmarshal i create three POJO classes : Root GeneralInfo and Doctype

My problem is that i can

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;
```

but i get "import ... cannot be resolved" when i :

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;
```

anyone have an idea how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of EclipseLink are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `@XmlPath` annotation was introduced in EclipseLink 2.1, since you ca see the `org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations` package but not `@XmlPath` you are most likely using EclipseLink 2.0.  As of today (October 14, 2011) the current release is EclipseLink 2.3.

Releases of EclipseLink can be obtained here:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

For more information on `@XmlPath`

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlPath

Comment: @achraf - If you are using EclipseLink 2.3 you could definitely see  `org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath`.  To confirm you are using 2.3 you could run the following:  `System.out.println(org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersionString());`